# New line after x pixels when adding to a label (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Currently when I write to a label, it will write only one line, and this sometimes disappears off the edge of the label, like so:

[image: Label issues]

Here is an example of the code I am using to write to the label:

```
def updateLabel(self, event):
    global string
    global labelContents
    global windowCommand
    global currentEnvironment
    if event != "no input":
        windowCommand = self.getEntry(event)
        labelDisplay = "> " + windowCommand
        labelContents += labelDisplay
        labelContents += "\n"
        self.checkLabel()
        string.set(labelContents)
        self.textEntry.delete(0, END)
        self.master.after(0, play)
    else:
        self.checkLabel()
        string.set(labelContents)

labelContents += "You have died. Game over." + "\n"
labelContents += "You scored {0}.".format(score) + "\n"
app.updateLabel("no input")
```

I would like to know if there was any way to force it to a new line after a certain amount of pixels (the label width) without having to go through and add "\n" everywhere (as that last line is 1 of ~150 possibilities).

Answer (score 4):

Label widget has a perfect option for that: `wraplength`.

```py
label = Label(parent, text="This is a really long text; " * 5, wraplength=200)
```

From the [Label's documentation on effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method):

> Determines when a label’s text should be wrapped into multiple lines.
>  This is given in screen units. Default is 0 (no wrapping).

Comment: That does work, but due to having the label at a fixed height, information is popped off the top of the label when the are 15 lines. This is checked by the number of "\n"'s in the string "labelContents". Because of this, when the label wraps the text, the program doesn't see the new line, and writes it at the bottom of the label, where it cannot be seen.

Comment: @Jon I see. Could be a solution to use one Label widget for each entry? So instead of appending, you only have to place the new label at the bottom.

Comment: I think because of the way the whole program works, that would work, as there are many places that the program adds to the label. Also, the window itself is a fixed size, so I think we'd run into the same problem with multiple labels. Thanks though.